# Hide Drag and Drop semi transparent preview in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

I have an application where I drag imageviews, everytime when I start dragging, a semi transparent copy of the image appear, [here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWJzI.png) ( the red points is where is my cursor )

Is there any way to disable this preview ? it cause wierd bugs when the application is run in XUbuntu, double the image and is completely useless for my application